# Swift decodable - decode json having base64 encoded string

Tags: ios, swift, base64, decode, codable

I am trying to decode JSON response that has encoded base64.

Example JSON:

```
{ "contract": "JVBERi0xLjQKJeLjz9MKNSAwIG9iago8PC9UeXBlL1hPYmplY3QvQ29sb3JTcGFjZS9EZXZpY2V", "isSuccess": true }
```

- How can I decode base64 to string?

My code & Model:

```
struct ruleModel: Codable {
    let contract: String?
    let isSuccess: Bool?
 }


let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let response = try decoder.decode(ruleModel.self, from: result! as! Data)
print(response)
```

Decoding Error:

```
dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "The given data was not valid JSON.", underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around line 1, column 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around line 1, column 0., NSJSONSerializationErrorIndex=0})))
```

Comment: The error has nothing to do with base64 decoding. What is `result`?

Comment: @burnsi  `result` is  data response.

Comment: try `print(String(data: result, encoding: .utf8))` to see what this data contains. According to the error it is not JSON.

Comment: And provide the way you aquire the result object.

Comment: Could your print `print("Hex: \((result as! Data).map { String(format: "%02hhX", $0) }.joined())`?

Comment: First of all, as a rule of thumb, please do not name your Structs and Classes starting with lowercase letter :) 

Secondly, can you update the code with how you exactly get the result?
I've run your code in playground, and when I've set the JSON object as Data, it decoded to the Struct with no problems.